# BPEL switch-case in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, soa, bpel

I'm using netbeans to develop some BPEL but can't figure out how to add a switch-case block, it's not in the palette anywhere.
I'm using netbeans 6.5.
Any ideas?

Switch is definitely a valid element: http://charltonb.typepad.com/weblog/2003/08/bpel4ws_switch_.html 
It's also mentioned in the course materials I'm running through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just inserting the switch in the xml source itself?  Not sure if Netbeans would support it but it is defined in the standard for BPEL markup.

Comment: I've tried that. It breaks the of the flow so makes the graphical tool useless.
I've since discovered that that form of flow control isn't supported by the tool.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure a switch element even exists.

You might have no other option but to [use a couple of `else-if`'s](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/55/bpel_gsg_palette.html#usingifelement).

Comment: Switch is definitely a valid element:
http://charltonb.typepad.com/weblog/2003/08/bpel4ws_switch_.html
it's also mentioned in the course materials I'm running through.